# Is Cross Validation useless unless the Hypotheses are nested?

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting, ridge-regression

If I generate many random models (without considering the data at all) in a regression setting simply by randomly assigning coefficient values and then evaluating these models over the dataset with an error metric and choosing the best model based on this error metric would I still run into overfitting?

Eventually we will end up with the OLS solution (see comments). If this is the case how is Cross Validation different than this procedure? For example in a Ridge or Lasso regression setting I am still generating a bunch of models (indexed by $\lambda$) and evaluating them on unseen data segment and choosing the best one.

It seems to me that CV works well with standard regularization methods like Ridge and Lasso is because the tried models are somewhat nested (i.e. Ridge is ordered by Rademacher complexity). Hence the Structural Risk Minimization principle kicks in. Otherwise CV looks like a dead end effort. If we use cross validation to compare bunch of unrelated models we will end up with the random model generation scenario that I described above.

Under the Structural Risk Minimization framework, for example in SVM, one bounds the error and reduces the model complexity. So how does CV actually achieve the same effect when applied in conjunction with regularization methods? What to do when compared models are not nested?

Comment: Generating random models and choosing the one with least error is asymptotically (if you do this long enough) equivalent to OLS regression because OLS solution minimizes squared error.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc: this is like the monkeys typing Shakespeare/the Bible/whatever text you choose: if you produce *many* random model, eventually the least squares solution will be among them. Eventualy even a sequence of $k$ times the least squares solution of the *CV test cases*. And that will then be selected [if you use squared error as performance criterion].

Comment: Random feature learning is also a thing (see the Random Vector Functional-Link network, which the controversial Extreme Learning Machine is derived from).

Comment: The premise of this question is very confusing. CV can sometimes be ineffective, but I don't see (1) how its failure modes have anything to do with nested vs. non-nested hypotheses or Rademacher complexity, or (2) how comparing non-nested models has anything to do with comparing randomly generated models.

Comment: @Paul The implicit assumption behind CV is that the number of hypotheses compared is low. If we have a lot of models to compare it will overfit. Usually in a Ridge setting we have plenty of lambda settings, hence quite many hypotheses. However the reason it works in this scenario is because the hypotheses are nested.

Comment: OK, that makes some sense: CV has less risk of overfitting if one is using it to optimize a parameter that indexes a nested sequence of hypothesis sets. But it doesn't follow that non-nested CV is useless, nor that it has anything to do with random model generation.

Comment: @Paul random generated model is an analogy to show what happens when one comes up with a lot of unrelated models. You overfit like OLS. Samething happens with a lot of non nested models in CV.

Comment: But OLS doesn't always overfit. It's just not robust under all circumstances. Similarly, calling CV with non-nested models useless because it could overfit seems to extrapolate too much from the analogy.

Comment: @Paul Depends on your definition of overfit. Both by results of Stein and the proof that a lambda exists that Ridge performs better than OLS means OLS overfits more than Ridge. It is always relative.

Comment: There's almost always going to be a better-performing method and there's almost always going to be training optimism. Defining overfitting that broadly is meaningless.

Comment: @Paul OK let's not get philosophical. I am just trying to figure out how to select a good model when I have very many non-nested models. Simply doing CV and picking the lowest error doesn't work for me. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work for you? If you want to know empirically how well CV-based model selection performs, then (1) set aside a test set (2) split the training set into K folds (3) pick best model using K-fold cross validation on training set. Then train your favorite single-model approach on the same training data and predict on the test data. See which one does better.

Comment: And if you don't like this kind of many-model selection, I actually agree with you, I prefer to choose my model carefully using domain-specific theoretical considerations and exploratory analysis. I avoid this hyper-empirical "throw everything and see what sticks" approach of many-model CV selection. But if you insist on choosing from many models using pure, automated empiricism, I don't think you have any other good options.

Comment: @Paul CV or information criteria. Problem doesn't change. When you compare many models with IC you end up overfitting as well. Set aside whatever you  like. Multiple comparison on the same data and then pick a model approach overfits for many non-nested models. "See which one does better" means you are back to square one, you just extended the validation set.

Comment: many models + mindless empiricism = overfitting. There is no getting around that equation. But one thing you could do is repeated CV - see if the selected model is the same on different CV runs. That would give you a better sense of whether the selected model is being selected by pure random chance.

Comment: Another conceptually interesting approach is Bayesian model averaging. Instead of selecting a single best model, you ensemble all candidates in a weighted average, with the weights being proportional to the Bayesian evidence in favor of each model.

Comment: @Paul Obviously if I had a prior defined over this pool of non-nested hypotheses I wouldn't need CV. I don't understand your idea of Bayesian evidence in this context.

Comment: Just a different approach you could consider. If you insist on CV then use repeated CV, or keep a separate holdout that isn't touched by the CV process. Neither strategy prevents overfitting; as I said, many models + mindless empiricism = overfitting inevitably. But repeated CV gives you a better sense of whether any particular model consistently does the best out-of-sample, and a separate holdout will provide a more realistic estimate of the CV-selected model's out-of-sample performance.

Answer (score 6):

> My logic tells me the answer is yes.

And, as @amoeba pointed out: your logic is right.

> how is Cross Validation different than this procedure? 
>   CV in itself has *nothing* to do with your overfitting. CV is just a scheme how to retain independent cases to test some model.

Note that if you select a model based on the CV results, this **model selection procedure** (including the CV) **is actually part of your training**.

You need to do an independent validation (rather, verification) of that final model (for which you can again use *another* CV as a strategy to retain cases independent of the training - see nested cross validation) in order to obtain a reliable estimate of its generalization performance.

To reiterate: the problem is not the CV, the problem is the data-driven model optimization (selection).

> From this perspective random model generation should in theory overfit less than a penalized regression as my evaluation is on a bigger unseen data segment.

This I don't understand: why would the unseen data size differ?

> Is there something in CV procedure that somehow mitigates the multiple testing problem?

No.

The only property of CV that slightly helps with multiple testing compared to a single split is that CV eventually tests all available cases, and is thus subject to somewhat smaller variance uncertainty due to the limited number of tested cases. This won't help much compared to limiting the search space (i.e. restricting the number of comparisons), though.

Comment: When not much training data is available fitting a model through cross-validation alone is reasonable. I think the tradeoff between using all the data for fitting or saving a portion just for validation is not that clear cut in many circumstances

Comment: @Nat: when not much training data is available, I'd recommend to use as much expert domain knowledge as possible and try to avoid any data-driven tuning by cross validation (or an internal single split): few cases mean the CV estimates are uncertain, which will hamper the optimization anyways. CV is better than a single split, but it cannot work miracles.

Comment: What would non-data driven model selection look like? Is that like non-data-driven decision making? If I minimize MSE is that data-driven? What if I minimize MSPE?

Comment: @Nat: Example for not data-driven model selection: Deciding pre-processing and possibly also model complexity by knowledge about the application at hand, such as: the processes that generate the data and the information to be retrieved, other information or confounding factors involved. Minimizing errors is data-driven: you minimize some error you observe *within* your available data. This is necessary for fitting model parameters, but it is in my experience often possible to limit the the number of so-called hyperparameters/restrict the hyperparameter search space. (I typically <100 cases)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
Tuning or selecting a model based on cross-validation is essentially trying to minimize the prediction error (e.g., mean-squared prediction error). You select a model conditional on some subset of input data and predict the output at the left out locations. Intuitively, it is a prediction because you are evaluating the model at out of sample locations. Your question is what happens if your set of candidate models are independent of the input data (i.e., you don't use any data when randomly generating models).

This assumption is not that different than any other model fitting procedure. For example, if I start with a parameterized model, and the parameters could be any real number, then I also have an infinite set of candidate models. We both still need to select the best model from the set of possible models by minimizing some error metric. Therefore, both of our model choices are conditional on some training data (perhaps a subset of all the training data if using cross-validation). You don't specify an error metric so lets assume it is mean-squared error (MSE). I pick model parameters and thereby my model using some black box procedure assuming MSE metric conditional on training data. You pick your model from your set of random models assuming MSE metric conditional on training data.

Do we choose the same model? It depends on if you started with different sets of candidate models.

Do we overfit the data? It depends on the set of candidate models we started with and the training data.

Do we know we overfit the data? If we do cross-validation then we can check the prediction error.

ORIGINAL RESPONSE:
In a broad sense, there is some signal in the data and some noise. When we overfit we are essentially fitting the noise.

In cross-validation, we leave out portions of the data when fitting and assess the error when predicting the left out points. It is similar to having training and test data in that we are measuring an out of sample error. The model must generalize well regardless of what points are omitted. If we fit the noise the model will not generalize well. The set of models we are comparing likely does not include those that try to interpolate a data point when it is omitted from the training data. If the model behaves this way (e.g., random behavior to improve fit) then it is likely we do not have a reasonable general model fitting procedure and cross-validation can't help us.

If you have an infinite set of models and an infinite amount of time then I guess in theory you could generate a model that was as good or better than any model that was generate through any other procedure. How will you know which model from your infinite set it is though? If it is the model that interpolates the training data, then yes it will overfit when the training data is noisy.